# Trigger firebase function on anonymous user upgrade

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Firebase functions provide a `functions.auth.user().onCreate()` and `functions.auth.user().onDelete()` handler. However when an anonymous user is linked to a new email user using `linkWithCredential()` as follows no action is triggered. Is there a way to handle and be notified of such occurances within Firebase functions?

```js
auth.currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential)
  .then(function(usercred) {
    var user = usercred.user;
    console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no trigger for this event.  There is just account creation and deletion.  This would be a feature request that you could file with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can now use [blocking functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-blocking-events?gen=1st) to get around this. Since I assume a sign-in event will be fired after linkWithCredential() you should be able to capture the account upgrade event.

Comment: this is true, based on my reading of the new docs